# Android studio how to send data from one fragment to another without recreating the view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, barcode-scanner

by using [yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner) I have implemented barcode scanning.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:padding="10dp">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.budiyev.android.codescanner.CodeScannerView
        android:id="@+id/scanner_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:autoFocusButtonColor="@android:color/white"
        app:autoFocusButtonVisible="true"
        app:flashButtonColor="@android:color/white"
        app:flashButtonVisible="true"
        app:frameColor="@android:color/white"
        app:frameCornersSize="50dp"
        app:frameCornersRadius="0dp"
        app:frameAspectRatioWidth="1"
        app:frameAspectRatioHeight="1"
        app:frameSize="0.75"
        app:frameThickness="2dp"
        app:maskColor="#77000000"/>
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ScanFragment**

```
public class ScanFragment extends Fragment {
private CodeScanner mCodeScanner;

public String scan;

@Override
@Nullable
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Activity activity = getActivity();
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scan, container, false);
    CodeScannerView scannerView = root.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view);
    mCodeScanner = new CodeScanner(activity, scannerView);

    mCodeScanner.setDecodeCallback(result -> {
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(activity, result.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
                scan = result.getText();
                goBack(scan);

    });
    scannerView.setOnClickListener(v -> mCodeScanner.startPreview());
    return root;
}


public void goBack(String scanResult)
{
    Fragment fr=new NewFormFragment();
    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("SCAN", scanResult);
    fr.setArguments(args);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCodeScanner.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mCodeScanner.releaseResources();
    super.onPause();
}}
```

I am calling the above fragment through my main fragment

```
 @BindView(R.id.start_scan)
ImageButton startScan;

public class NewFormFragment extends Fragment {
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_form_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        bindListners();
        installStatusSpinner.setEnabled(false);
        //imsiNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ctRatio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnMaterial.setEnabled(false);
        linearLayoutMaterial.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayoutImsi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayoutSignOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        meterType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        disableTextViews();
        disableMeterGroup();
        setupUI(mScrollView);
    }
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("install_id")) {
        isNewInstall = false;
        editInstallId = arguments.getString("install_id");
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_fragment_edit_form));
        setEditData();
        //imsiNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayoutImsi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linearLayoutSignOff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ctRatio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        resetFormButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.title_fragment_new_form));
    }
    if(getArguments()!=null)
    {
        selectedMeterNo = getArguments().getString("SCAN");
        smartMsnSpinner.setText(selectedMeterNo);
    }

    /*mCoordinatesReceiver = new CoordinatesReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Common.GetCoordinatesAction());
    getActivity().registerReceiver(mCoordinatesReceiver, intentFilter);*/
    return view;
}

 public void bindListners()
 {
     startScan.setOnClickListener(startScanning);

 } 
 private final View.OnClickListener startScanning = v -> {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.start_scan){
        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new ScanFragment();
        replaceFragment(fragment);
    }
};
public void replaceFragment(Fragment someFragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, someFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

Now when I click on my scan button I am able to see my scan fragment view. After the successful scan, I am passing the scanned text to may `NewFormFragment`. But there is an issue, I don't want to re-create the `NewFormFragment` view. I want to pass my scanned text to the `NewFormFragment` by retaining the previous view.

**Note:** When I run my app `NewFormFragment` is called.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with Broadcast receivers/Listeners

Comment: @BHARADWAJMarripally can you please provide me any good example ?